# How to stream and collect instance methods result from an collection of object?

Tags: java, java-stream

The requirement is to stream a Set of Object, filter on some criteria, and collect only the employeeID in a Set of String

```
class Employee {
    private String empId;
    private int type;

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
}
```

While filtering the following statement

```
employees.stream().filter(x-> x.getType() == 1).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

returns a `Set<Employee>` instead i want to only collect empId i.e. `Set<String>`

Note: Cannot make instance variable anything other than private.

Comment: Use [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method to convert from `Employee` to `String`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map()` to map the `Employee` instances into the corresponding Employee IDs.

```
Set<String> empIds =
    employees.stream()
             .filter(x-> x.getType() == 1)
             .map(Employee::getEmpId)
             .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
employees
   .stream()
   .filter(x-> x.getType() == 1)
   .map(Employee::getEmpId)
   .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

will return the `Set<String>` which contain Employee Ids.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the original `Employee` as well, you can instead use `toMap`.

```
Map<String, Employee> employeesById = employees.stream()
        .filter(e-> e.getType() == 1)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getEmpId, Function.identity()));
```

This is especially useful, if you need to resolve the employees later. If this does not apply, above solutions are to be preferred.

Also, the `Set` can still be obtained with:

```
Set<String> employeeIds = employeesById.keySet();
```